# angular parse massive amounts of data from rest api

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest

I'm very new to Angular / TS, sorry if this is a noobie question.
I've to implement a rest request towards a server in angular. The problem is that one element contains ~ 260 properties. Later i'll have to display ~90-100 of them. Is there a way to intelligently parse the data from the rest api, without needing to write hundreds of lines of code?

The stuff that i get back looks something like this

```
[{ "field one" : [],
 "field two": 1,
 "field three": "some text",
 "field four": null and like 255 more of these. },
  and like 40k more of theabove]
```

Comment: I haven't quite understood what are you trying to achieve, but you could use `Object.keys` followed by a `map` and loop the result array to display the data dinamically.

Comment: You have to type out every property you want to display in the html. There is no way to just filter out the desired 100 properties out of the 260 available.

Comment: If you wrote the API you're integrating with this is defintiely the point to go back and refactor your API rather than try and integrate with it. For example if you're displaying a sequential list of fields actually called "field 1", "field 2"... then return them as an array that you can return as `"fields": []` and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should search about DTO (data transfer object).
If you think about your API programing maybe help us.
For example I use .NET Core REST API,
I've created a database table with many columns and relations with many tables.
Then I've converted the tables to DTOs with mapper. Then I use many many columns or table REST API.

Comment: Hi Mustafa! Welcome to the site! Could you perhaps flesh this answer out a bit more? It's being flagged because it suggests that the OP do a search, and you sort of define what they should find, but it's a bit ambiguous. Could you add a little more detail? Thank you!!